# How can I remove values from a ranking system if they are a positive value k apart?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following code:

```
def compute_ranks(graph, k):
    d = .8 #dampening factor
    loops = 10
    ranks = {}
    npages = len(graph)
    for page in graph:
        ranks[page] = 1.0 / npages
    for c in range(0, loops):
        newranks = {}
        for page in graph:
            newrank = (1-d) / npages
            for node in graph:
                if page in graph[node]:
                    newrank = newrank + d * (ranks[node]/len(graph[node]))
            newranks[page] = newrank
        ranks = newranks
     return ranks
```

Alright so now suppose I want to not allow any items that can collude with each other. If I have an item dictionary

```
g = {'a': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'b':['a'], 'c':['d'], 'd':['a']}
```

For any path A==>B, I don't want to allow paths from B==>A that are at a distance at or below my number k.

For example if k = 0, then the only path I would not allow is A==>A.

However if k = 2, then I would not allow the links A==>A as before but also links such as D==>A, B==>A, or A==>C.

I know this is very confusing and a majority of my problem comes from not understanding exactly what this means.

Here's a transcript of the question:

```
# Question 2: Combatting Link Spam

# One of the problems with our page ranking system is pages can 
# collude with each other to improve their page ranks.  We consider 
# A->B a reciprocal link if there is a link path from B to A of length 
# equal to or below the collusion level, k.  The length of a link path 
# is the number of links which are taken to travel from one page to the 
# other.

# If k = 0, then a link from A to A is a reciprocal link for node A, 
# since no links needs to be taken to get from A to A.

# If k=1, B->A would count as a reciprocal link  if there is a link 
# A->B, which includes one link and so is of length 1. (it requires 
# two parties, A and B, to collude to increase each others page rank).

# If k=2, B->A would count as a reciprocal link for node A if there is
# a path A->C->B, for some page C, (link path of length 2),
# or a direct link A-> B (link path of length 1).

# Modify the compute_ranks code to 
#   - take an extra input k, which is a non-negative integer, and 
#   - exclude reciprocal links of length up to and including k from 
#     helping the page rank.
```

Comment: @robert: If you read the question, the OP said that it's a past homework problem that he couldn't solve.

Comment: confused, if you don't allow "links such as D==>A, B==>A, or A==>C", then what do you allow?

Comment: All right, I think I understand the quoted text, but the problem is that it doesn't contain a question. I assume the task is to assign ranks to pages, and the given dict shows how they link to each other. What I don't get is, what is the definition of page rank?

Comment: @xvatar in that case nothing. All the page ranks would be equal.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I edited the question to contain the full homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
def Colluding(p1,p2,itemDict,k, time):
if k >= len(itemDict)/2:
    return True
if k == 0:
    if time == 0:
        if p1 == p2 and p1 in itemDict[p2]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    if time == 1:
        if p1 in itemDict[p2]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
for p in itemDict[p1]:
    if Colluding(p1,p,itemDict,k-1,1) and p == p2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
return False

def compute_ranks(graph, k):
    d = 0.8 # damping factor
    numloops = 10
    ranks = {}
    npages = len(graph)
    for page in graph:
        ranks[page] = 1.0 / npages
    for i in range(0, numloops):
        newranks = {}
        for page in graph:
            newrank = (1 - d) / npages
            for node in graph:
                if page in graph[node] and not Colluding(page, node, graph, k,0):
                    newrank = newrank + d * (ranks[node]/len(graph[node]))
            newranks[page] = newrank
        ranks = newranks
    return ranks
```

Thanks to @Ken for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to introduce a recursive method which detects a collusion.  Something like:

```
def Colluding(p1,p2,itemDict,k):
    if p1 == p2:
        return True
    elif k == 0:
        return False
    else p2 in itemDict[p1]:
        return True
    for p in itemDict[p1]:
        if Colluding(p1,p,itemDict,k-1):
            return True
    return False
```

Then where it says `if item in itemDict[node]` you would have `if item in itemDict[node] and not Colluding(item,node,itemDict,k)` or something similar.

That does a [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) which might not be the best choice if there are a lot of colluding links at a small depth (say A->B->A) since they may only be found after several full depth searches. You may be able to find another way which does a [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) in that case. Also, if you have a lot of links, it might be worth trying to convert to a loop instead because Python might have a stack overflow problem if you use recursion. The recursive algorithm is what came to my mind first because it seems natural to traverse trees using recursion.

Note: Since this is help with homework, I have not tested it and some comparisons might not be quite right and need to be adjusted in some way.

Comment: Else p2 in itemDict[p1] What did you mean here? That's invalid syntax. You can't have anything after else

Comment: You're absolutely right, that is not valid syntax. I was trying to get the idea across, which seems to have worked since you say you figured it out below. An `elif` would at least be valid syntax, but I'm not going to put any more work into solving the problem since you already solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I also took this course.. and I proposed the following solution. Basically, all we need is "all reciprocal links". The following procedure calculated all the reciprocal links, given a graph and level k. it returns a list of tuples, denoting a reciprocal link (node1, node2). all you need to do is to check if (node,page) are NOT in this list ot calculate rank.

```
def get_reciprocal_links(graph, k):
reci=[]
for node in g:
    for ele in g[node]:
        got = False
        work = []
        i=0
        if node == ele and i == k:
            reci.append((node,ele))
            break
        if ele in g:
            for e in g[ele]:
                work.append(e)

        while i < k:
            if node in work:
                reci.append((node,ele))
                got = True
                break
            else:
                i=i+1
                check=work.pop()
                if check in g:
                    for e in g[check]:
                        work.append(e)
        if got == True:
            continue
return reci
```